# Java Swing - switch locale dynamically at runtime

Tags: java, swing, internationalization

I understand how to internationalize a java program, but I have a problem.
Language in my program can be switched anytime, but my program can exist in many states, which means that it may or may not have several JLabels, JPanels, JFrames, etc, open. Is there a class or a method which will update the current GUI to the switched language, or does it have to be done manually?

If nothing else works, I'll just require user to restart the program to switch the language, but runtime change would be nice...

Comment: Do you have localized strings for each possible language? How are you currently fetching those strings? Or are the strings currently hardcoded into each element?

Comment: I haven't acutally written the program yet, just a couple of lines, exactly to avoid that problem. I'm open to everything!

Comment: What kind of java program will you be writing?  A web app using JavaEE/JSF/etc or something else?

Comment: @jahroy JLabels, JPanels and JFrames are all part of Java Swing. This is not likely to be a web application, but the principles are the same regardless.

Comment: That's what I thought (just wanted to confirm before editing tags).  Actually the principles could vary.  My understanding is that the OP understands the approach to java localization, but is looking for a solution to dynamically change the content of rendered components on the fly.  If this were a webapp (with popups and/or multiple windows and tabs) you might use AJAX/push to do this.

Comment: If you are lazy, you can try this https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/c10n/wiki/Overview

Answer (score 2):

The solution generally used is to have a hash of user-facing strings in a central manager class. You make a call into that class whenever you want to populate a field with data:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText(LocalizationManager.get("MY_LABEL_TEXT"));
```

Inside the `LocalizationManager` you will have to fetch the current language of the program, then look up the appropriate string for `MY_LABEL_TEXT` in the appropriate language. The manager then returns the now 'localized' string, or some default if the language or string isn't available.

Think of the manager as a slightly more complicated Map; it's mapping from a key (ie 'MY_LABEL_TEXT') to what you want to display ("Good day!" or "Bienvenido!") depending on which language you're in. There are a lot of ways to implement this, but you want the manager to be static or a singleton (loaded once) for memory/performance reasons.

For instance: (1)

```
public class LocalizationManager {
  private SupportedLanguage currentLanguage = SupportedLanguage.ENGLISH;//defaults to english
  private Map<SupportedLanguage, Map<String, String>> translations;

  public LocalizationManager() {
    //Initialize the strings. 
    //This is NOT a good way; don't hardcode it. But it shows how they're set up.

    Map<String, String> english = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> french = new HashMap<String, String>();

    english.set("MY_LABEL_TEXT", "Good day!");
    french.set("MY_LABEL_TEXT", "Beinvenido!");//is that actually french?

    translations.set(SupportedLanguage.ENGLISH, english);
    translations.set(SupportedLanguage.FRENCH, french);
  }

  public get(String key) {
    return this.translations.get(this.currentLanguage).get(key);
  }

  public setLanguage(SupportedLanguage language) {
    this.currentLanguage = language;
  }

  public enum SupportedLanguage {
    ENGLISH, CHINESE, FRENCH, KLINGON, RUSSIAN; 
  }
}
```

(1) I haven't tested this, nor is it a singleton, but it's an off the cuff example.

Comment: So I would invoke the manager upon language switch and it would update all the strings that are to be updated (which are under his jurisdiction)?

Comment: Could You possibly tell me more about LocalizationManager(s), I can't seem to find anything with Google?

Comment: @Karlovsky120 I've updated my response to try and provide an example. Don't update all the strings on switching a language; do it once. Better yet, do it lazily, but that's the next step. If you have an interface like I've shown, you can improve on the implementation.

Comment: not good enough: that's taking care of the storage only. The downvote is for re-inventing the wheel in that respect - the way to define locale specific key/value pairs is a ResourceBundle, the singleton to store those is the UIManager and the way to make the manager aware of the localization is to add the ResourceBundle). The challenge is to update the component properties dynamically ..

Comment: @kleopatra Correct (if trivial) assessment of wheel re-invention. You should provide a full-bodied solution so that Karlovsky has something to go off of.