# How to internationalize all UI lables in java

Tags: java, internationalization

I need to internationalize my software to French language. I did the following code.

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("basic", new Locale("en", "US"));
lblUsername.setText(bundle.getString("username"));
lblPassword.setText(bundle.getString("password"));
btnLogin.setText(bundle.getString("login"));
```

This is my login form. My property files are OK and this is working on login UI. After the login to the system, I need to change all UI labels of all UIs according to the selected language on login form. Can anyone give me a solution for this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Well, store the selected langage in some variable, and use this variable in other classes to load the appropriate bundle.

Comment: I didn't get you.. please can you explain it more..

Comment: Are you working with jsf? or is a desktop app?

Answer (score 1):

Dont hardcode locale like this:

```
 ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("basic", new Locale("en", "US"));
```

Get `Locale` instance from jsf/spring or whatever framework you use. Provide *.properties files for all locales that your application supports.

Check also:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13251/java-best-way-to-work-with-locales-in-swing-with-change-at-runntime

[Java Swing - switch locale dynamically at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011180/java-swing-switch-locale-dynamically-at-runtime)

[Changing locale at runtime in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615973/changing-locale-at-runtime-in-swing)

[Swing Internationalization - How to update language at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810454/swing-internationalization-how-to-update-language-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the locale of the language that was  selected on the login form and then make use of it when you generate your UIs after login. So instead of using

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("basic", new Locale("en", "US"));
```

you then would use

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("basic", classWhereTheLocaleIsStores.getLocale());
```

Answer (score 0):

so if is a desktop app, you need to store the locale selected, and before loading the application, set the locale to choose right properties, for example:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("baseNameOfyouProperties",
                    localeSelectedBYUser);
```

the answer above explain the same, the important thing is that you save the locale selected.

Comment: I need to change all labels of all UIs after login. As an example When I login to the system, it appears MainMenu UI. I need to change the main menu UI labels also.

Comment: so you need to know when and where load the rest of the components, and do it the same, creat a method that save the locale and reloading all the sections with this locale.  I don't know if changing the locale system this change the ui...but take a look to safe time..but i don't believe that this works.. http://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml

Comment: take a look at this post maybe can help you if you are working with swing.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298080/java-best-way-to-work-with-locales-in-swing-with-change-at-runntime